# Large file upload using plain node.js

Tags: node.js

Anyone knows of a way to accomplish this without using external modules?

Everything I find out uses things like express, that's not going to do for me.

By the way, with *large* I mean > 2MB but < 100MB.

Comment: "Close: There are either too many possible answers [...]" Yeah right, then post one, pal.

Answer (score 0):

Regardless of the server, you can use the bare [http.requesst()](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v6.x/docs/api/http.html#http_class_http_clientrequest) part of the core HTTP module and use the stream interface to avoid storing ~60MB in memory per upload. Then you could cover all the headers and other cases for your uploads.

What you may end up doing is re-implementing many things that are in an existing community module. Finding, reading over, and understanding an existing module that the community relies on is the path I would take if I were in your situation.